# Is there possible to automate packaging process in Indesign CS3?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Question nr.1 - Every time I complete a job in indesign, I need to package it. I do it manually, but is there a way to do it automatic?

Question nr.2 - Is there a possibility to create .inx file from CC indesign? Now I make .idml from CC version, then open it on CS4 and only then convert to CS3.

Comment: What do you mean by “package”? Is it “collecting all necessary files in one place”?

Comment: Yes, in indesign: File -> Package

Comment: Could you please clarify, what do you mean by “automatic” then? The most sure way to automate things in InDesign is by scripting…

Answer (score 1):

I would do this three ways:

1. Assign a [Keyboard Shortcut](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.adobe.com%2Fen_US%2Findesign%2Fcs%2Fusing%2FWS57E36B38-B2EB-4255-BAB5-19CCCB4319BFa.html&ei=4L1rU6yYGPSlsQTN_YHICA&usg=AFQjCNF2_moQXeuHFtzH0e5mPXR3G6WyhA&sig2=Br6NRMyXbun4qewQ3f37KA&bvm=bv.66111022,d.cWc)! to make it quicker accessing the Package button.
2. Adobe InDesign has built in scripting functions that give you underlying access to key functions. You can script with Javascript cross platform or AppleScript for Mac. Here are two links for that endeavor:

   - [Adobe Knowledgebase Article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WS0836C26E-79F9-4c8f-8150-C36260164A87a.html)
   - [CS3 Scripting](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/indesign_cs3_scripting_read_me.pdf)
3. Create simple macros using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), or [Atomac](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/atomac)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe there is some way to get this package function script?

Comment: I did a rudimentary search and found two links of interest: [InDesign Secrets on how to Package Quickly](http://indesignsecrets.com/package-docs-quickly.php) and [Here is a script to auto package files into a directory (works Mac and Windows)](http://kasyan.ho.com.ua/package_for_archive.html).